# Error Code: 1109 Unknown table 'CONSUMER' in field list

Tags: mysql

I am looking to make a table which is manipulated through store procedures.
I have 2 procedures that do select and updates. First one executes perfectly, but the last one is having an issue. It definitely feels like mysql parser issue. I hope I can find some help here because it is due soon for a project. Once the second sp is run, every subsequent update statement fails whether through an SP or just basic query, until I delete the record; then I can insert again then update through basic query call. I need to use SPs because I am communicating to a web server running NodeJS. I am using the node-mysql package. I am using mysql-5.7.

SECOND SP ERROR : Error Code: 1109 Unknown table 'CONSUMER' in field list

Thanks,
timecatcher

TABLE SCHEMA

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONSUMER (
        signUpVerified BIT(1),
        signUpTimeStamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        loggedIn BIT(1),
        loginTimeStamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        consumerName VARCHAR(100),
        consumerEmail VARCHAR(254) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        consumerPassword VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        consumerAddress VARCHAR(100),
        consumerMapLocation VARCHAR(50),
        consumerMobileNumber VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        consumerBalance FLOAT,
        lastSessionID BINARY(32),
        consumerID INT(30) UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(consumerID)
    );
```

FIRST SP

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `CONSUMER_SIGN_UP_VERIFICATION`(IN lastSessionID BINARY(32), IN consumerEmail VARCHAR(254))
    BEGIN 
        IF ((consumerEmail IS NULL) OR (lastSessionID IS NULL)) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "EMAIL ADDRESS & SESSION ID REQUIRED";
        END IF;
        IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CONSUMER WHERE (CONSUMER.consumerEmail = consumerEmail) AND (CONSUMER.signUpVerified = b'0'))) THEN
            IF ((SELECT CONSUMER.signUpTimeStamp FROM CONSUMER WHERE CONSUMER.consumerEmail = consumerEmail) = CHECK_SESSION_ID(lastSessionID, CONCAT("SANTEX", consumerEmail))) THEN
                UPDATE CONSUMER SET CONSUMER.signUpVerified = b'1' WHERE CONSUMER.consumerEmail = consumerEmail;
            ELSE
                DELETE FROM CONSUMER WHERE CONSUMER.consumerEmail = consumerEmail;
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "THIS SIGN UP VERIFICATION EMAIL SETUP HAS BEEN TAMPERED WITH, SO PLEASE START A NEW ACCOUNT";
            END IF;
        ELSE 
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "THIS ACCOUNT IS ALREADY REGISTERED OR THERE IS NO ACCOUNT REGISTERED WITH THIS EMAIL ADDRESS";
        END IF;
    END
```

SECOND SP

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `CONSUMER_LOGIN`(IN consumerEmail VARCHAR(254), IN consumerPassword VARCHAR(20), OUT lastSessionID BINARY(32))
    BEGIN
        IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CONSUMER WHERE (CONSUMER.consumerEmail = consumerEmail) AND (CONSUMER.signUpVerified = b'1'))) THEN
            IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CONSUMER WHERE (CONSUMER.consumerEmail = consumerEmail) AND (CONSUMER.consumerPassword = consumerPassword))) THEN
                SELECT @consumerID := CONSUMER.consumerID FROM CONSUMER NATURAL JOIN CONSUMER_SESSION WHERE (CONSUMER.consumerEmail = consumerEmail) AND (CONSUMER.consumerPassword = consumerPassword) AND ((CONSUMER.loggedIn = b'1') OR ((CONSUMER_SESSION.loginTimeStamp != CONSUMER_SESSION.logoutTimeStamp) AND (CONSUMER_SESSION.logoutTimeStamp IS NULL)));
                IF (@consumerID IS NULL) THEN
                    SET @loginTimeStamp := NOW();
                    SET lastSessionID = CREATE_SESSION_ID(@loginTimeStamp, CONCAT("SANTEX", consumerEmail));
                    UPDATE CONSUMER SET CONSUMER.loggedIn = b'1', CONSUMER.lastSessionID = lastSessionID WHERE (CONSUMER.consumerEmail = consumerEmail) AND (CONSUMER.consumerPassword = consumerPassword);
                    INSERT INTO CONSUMER_SESSION(CONSUMER_SESSION.consumerID, CONSUMER_SESSION.loginTimeStamp, CONSUMER_SESSION.sessionID, CONSUMER_SESSION.logoutTimeStamp) VALUES(@consumerID, @loginTimeStamp, lastSessionID, NULL);
                ELSE 
                    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "THIS ACCOUNT HAS NOT LOGGED OUT FROM ITS PREVIOUS SESSION OR REQUESTED A PASSWORD RESET. PLEASE TRY AGAIN LATER";
                END IF;
            ELSE 
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "INCORRECT EMAIL ADDRESS OR PASSWORD";
            END IF;
        ELSE 
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "THERE IS NO ACCOUNT REGISTERED WITH THIS EMAIL ADDRESS OR SIGN UP VERIFICATION PENDING";
        END IF;
    END
```

Comment: are you creating the procedure in same DB where table exists?

Comment: Yea . . The select works perfectly but the update call on the second SP is causing the error; then it won't let me update query at all till I  delete that row.

Comment: The strange part is that the first SP makes similar calls but with no issues; like I mentioned earlier it could be mysql parser issue.

Comment: I am so sorry. My triggers file is 1500 lines of code. I made a mistake in the trigger by calling CONSUMER.loggedIn. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry. My triggers file is 1500 lines of code. I made a mistake in the trigger by calling CONSUMER.loggedIn. Thank you for your time